# How to trigger focus keyup for next render remaining char jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make dynamically text remaining, the code for row 1 is work. But not for the next row.

```js
var str = getStringForm(typeNarrative, nomor); // my str is equal of my text area html code 
$('#Scores').append(str);
(function($) {
  'use strict';
  $.fn.remainingCharsCounter = function() {
    return this.on('focus keyup', function() {
      var remainingChars = $(this).attr('maxlength') - $(this).val().length;
      $(this).next('.remainingChars').text(remainingChars).focus();;
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
  $('textarea.char-textarea').remainingCharsCounter().css('border', '1px solid #0000004f');
});

**getStringForm**
my string from here 

function getStringForm(typeNarrative, nomor) {
var str;
if (typeNarrative == "subtest" || typeNarrative == "SUBTEST") {
    str = `<div class="row NarrativeField" id="label` + nomor + `" style="text-align:center;margin-top:15px;">
     <div class="col-xs-2">
                <textarea id="NarrativeLong`+ nomor + `" class="k-textbox char-textarea" maxlength="2000" name="NarrativeLong` + nomor + `" data-bind="value:Narrative[` + nomor + `].NarrativeLong` + nomor + `" style="width:70%"></textarea>
                Remaining chars: <span class="remainingChars" style="font-size:8pt; font-weight:bold;"></span>                
            </div>               
            <a href="#" id="clearNarrative` + nomor + `" no="` + nomor + `" style="padding-left:4px;" onclick="clearNarrative(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>    
            </div>`;
} else if (typeNarrative == "IQ") {
    str = `<div class="row NarrativeField-IQ" id="label` + nomor + `" style="text-align:center;margin-top:15px;">
           <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="number" class="k-textbox char-textarea" maxlength="2000" id="Score`+ nomor + `" name="Score` + nomor + `" value="` + nomor + `" style="width:40%" readonly="readonly" />
                Remaining chars: <span class="remainingChars" style="font-size:8pt; font-weight:bold;"></span>
            </div>
           <div class="col-xs-8">
            <textarea id="NarrativeIQ`+ nomor + `" class="k-textbox char-textarea" maxlength="2000" name="NarrativeIQ` + nomor + `" style="width:70%"></textarea>
                Remaining chars: <span class="remainingChars" style="font-size:8pt; font-weight:bold;"></span>
            </div>
           <a href="#" id="clearNarrative` + nomor + `" no="` + nomor + `" style="padding-left:4px;" onclick="clearNarrative(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>    
           </div>`;
} else {
    str = "";
}
return str;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Score entered" id="label1">
  <textarea id="NarrativeLong1" class="char-textarea" name="NarrativeLong1" style="width:70%" maxlength="100"></textarea> Remaining chars: <span class="remainingChars" style="font-size:8pt; font-weight:bold;"></span>
</div>
```

i think keyup can't detect my new row field. Please help if there are any solution, thank you !

Comment: Can you post your getStringForm() function

Comment: I've added a function getStringForm, thanks for edit sir @KhalidKhan

Comment: Bro can you please also add that from where you got the typeNarrative variable, I mean for which element it contains the value

Comment: typeNarrative i got from parameter URL, and nomor variable i got from atribute of button when i click for add row. the atribute is for counter element. so every time i click the button, variable nomor value always added 1 @KhalidKhan